# When exactly can I set two equations equal to each other?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

I'm dealing with Lagrange multipliers and sometimes this leaves me with systems of 4 or 5 equations with 3 or 4 variables to solve for.

I know I can use substitution or elimination to solve them, but I've also seen sometimes two equations are set as equal to each other. When exactly can (and should) I do this?

Comment: The use of Lagrange multipliers should not leave you with an underdetermined system.  Can you give an example?  On my part, I would suggest getting a good understand of the Lagrange multiplier method, from a geometric point of view: https://books.google.com/books?id=rxOoCwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=zorich+mathematical+analysis+I&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiY9_qoit7QAhUGchQKHSzACjkQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=lagrange%20multipliers&f=false

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I follow... My question was actually focused on different methods of solving systems of equations. I'm trying to re-learn them because of Lagrange multipliers but I'm sure I'll use them for some other stuff as well. I've seen video-tutorials where they set two equations equal to each other, but I'm not sure when I should use that technique instead of substitution or elimination.

Comment: You should use whatever is more convenient.:)  I'd have an easier time helping you if you showed some examples demonstrating your difficulties.

Comment: I was just asking a generic question to see when I can use that method. I'm not too clever with math, so I'm not sure when it's convinient and when it can't be done.

Comment: "generic" is not effective in studying mathematics.  General understanding comes by studying specific examples, from simpler to harder.